# vscode typescript import intellisense css not working

Tags: css, typescript, visual-studio-code, module

The tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "noImplicitAny": false, //不需要显示地声明变量的类型为any
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules"
      }
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Currently my working environment supports style tips. If I import the css file manually:
[image]

If I want to import css files intelligently. Not work:
[image]

And there ara a style file in the folder named `ProductCollection.module.css`

How to fix it?

Think you!

Comment: Did yo find the answer?